# picture library no ribbon - How to check in all checked out pictures in one step?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a picture library. The versioning is turned on. My problem is that there is no option to check in all the checked out pictures in one step. The ribbon is completey missing from this library. How can I do this?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Picture Library in Sharepoint 2010 does not have the Ribbon GUI implemented in it, may be due to Microsoft has to deliver the product at time.

Picture library uses the same functionality as Sharepoint 2007.

You cant find ribbons in Picture library in Sharepoint 2010.

I hope i understand your question right

Thanks

Comment: Thanks your answer. I want to check in all the checked out files in one step. In my sharepoint site the users can upload more than 100 pictures and it is very hard to check in one by one. The missing ribbon is not the main thing.

Comment: There is one Solution in codeplex you can install
if you like i can provide you a link but I am not sure about it will work for the Picture library or not..
have a look at this, may be this can help you 
http://approvemultipleitems.codeplex.com/